# Catching keyboard shortcut outside of a browser using a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a project where I require a Push-to-Talk feature. I came to the conclusion that it may be do-able if I create an extension/plugin for Chrome/Firefox. The site is HTML5 based with WebRTC and I would like to implement a alternative plugin/extension users can download that will allow them to use push to talk outside of the browser. I.e. when the browser is minimized but the website is still open in the browser.

I want the plugin/extension to still listen for the  keystrokes. Is this do-able? Or do I need to create an application the users can download where the application will make a hook into the websites `webrtc API` and allow the users to use Push-to-Talk? I would rather like to stay away from the users having to download a `.exe` and much rather them just able to install a plugin/extension for their Chrome or Firefox browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is doable in principle in Chrome, as you can define [global shortcuts with `chrome.commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#usage):

Manifest:

```
"commands": {
  "push-to-talk": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
    },
    "description": "Activate push-to-talk",
    "global": true
  }
},
```

Background:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if(command == "push-to-talk"){
    // Do whatever you want, e.g. bring focus to browser,
    // pass commands to page with content scripts etc.
  }
});
```

Comment: Suggested global shortcuts can only be `Ctrl+Shift+[0..9]`

Comment: Would mouse clicks be able to be programmable? as in exe programs they do detect keyboard or mouse. Thanks for that info so far much appreciated! Also any info on firefox?

Comment: No, no mouse clicks. I don't know about FF and you should probably edit your question to include firefox-addon tag